# ASP.NET Core double validation replace commas with dots

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, double

I have an Input validation where I have to validate a double value. My problem is if I type for example "3.14" the validator accept it, but if I type "3,14", it will give error. The database also store it with dots, so I need a solution for replace comma with dot, and after validate it.

**EDIT**

There are some field which are not required.

Comment: Hi @kajahun123, It is a common issue and I think you can read [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6566) and check [this answer](https://gist.github.com/AndreasAmMueller/38c1a8d76ecd4450b4f75a479f3293c1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom model binders for decimal as well as double in your application like this

```
public class MyDecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue
           .Replace(",", "."),
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

And the same for double

```
public class MyDoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue/**/.Replace(",", "."),
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Then you need to add them to the services collection in your `Startup` class (Program class depending on your architecture)

```
  services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyDoubleBinderProvider());
});
```